# How to continue the process after the server is powered off and restarted?

Tags: linux

I am running a piece of code, and I have been running it for a month. There is no result yet. But because we need to repair the circuit here, the server needs to be powered off. Is there any way I can continue to run my code after restarting instead of running from the beginning?The server is a linux version.

Comment: Can it hibernate?

Comment: I cannot reach the server directly. Is there some way I can pause and keep the state of the running code, and resume it after restarting the server?

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line